# UiAutomatorviewer take screenshot in portrait mode (from an app which is in landscape mode)

Tags: android, uiautomatorviewer

Used Device: Emulator tablet Android 6.0
I am using an App which will be only displayed in landscape Mode.
When I try to get an Screen shot via uiautomatorviewer from App page, I get screenshot displayed in Portrait mode (also 180 degree rottated).

How Can I get screen shot in landscape view?

Thanks for any Hint and support.

[App dispalyed in landscape mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwrrM.png)

[Screenshot taken from uiautomatorviewer with 180 Degree rotated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iubMW.png)